# Best way to monitor pi

Tags: pi-3

So I have a bash script that sends a push notification to my phone with my pi's temperature and other info. If I wanted to constantly monitor the temp and check every 5-10 minutes, then send me a notification if my pi is above a threshold i set, what is the best way of doing this with the least overhead. Do I need to create an infinite loop or python script or a system service ? I'm using the pi as a media server which puts it under a heavy load often so I didnt want to do anything that would end up being cpu intensive/

Comment: I think performance concerns for something on a 10 minute cycle are unwarranted.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a Pi specific question, but you could create a `cron` job which runs every 10 minutes.

This will use minimal resources.

Answer (score 0):

cron job would be the best thing. Sounds like you already have the script written to send the info, now it just needs to check if the temp is above the threshold.